# Passing array to view in Code Igniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have a Customer controller with this function:

```
function index(){
    $query = $this->db->query("
    SELECT ELECTRICITY_BILL_ID,TOTAL_AMOUNT
    FROM _ELECTRICITY_BILL where CUSTOMER_LOCATION_ID = 16
    ");
     foreach ($query->result() as $row){
           $utility_array = array(
           'electricity_bill_id' => $row->ELECTRICITY_BILL_ID,
           'amount' => $row->TOTAL_AMOUNT);
         }
    $this->load->view('Customer',$utility_array);   
}
```

I have a Customer view with this:

```
<?php
  foreach($utility_array as $row) {
      echo $row['electricity_bill_id'];
      echo $row['amount'];
      echo "</br >";
   }

 ?>
```

I get two errors in my view:

```
Undefined variable: utility_array
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Answer (score 0):

change in controller with this.

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row){
       $utility_array['data'] = array(
       'electricity_bill_id' => $row->ELECTRICITY_BILL_ID,
       'amount' => $row->TOTAL_AMOUNT);
     }
```

In Customer view,

```
<?php
foreach($data as $row) {
  echo $row['electricity_bill_id'];
  echo $row['amount'];
  echo "</br >";
}
?>
```

this should work. try this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this controller code it will work:-

```
function index(){
    $query = $this->db->query(
        "SELECT ELECTRICITY_BILL_ID,TOTAL_AMOUNT
        FROM _ELECTRICITY_BILL where CUSTOMER_LOCATION_ID = 16"
    );
    foreach ($query->result() as $row){
        $utility_array['utility_array'] = array(
            'electricity_bill_id' => $row->ELECTRICITY_BILL_ID,
            'amount' => $row->TOTAL_AMOUNT
        );
    }
    $this->load->view('Customer',$utility_array);   
}
```

If you are passing array or object to view means you must assign the key for the variable. Using the key you can get the values in the view.
So for the **$utility_array** you should assign the key value.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

**In Controller**

```
function index(){
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT ELECTRICITY_BILL_ID,TOTAL_AMOUNT
                                FROM _ELECTRICITY_BILL wincache_refresh_if_changed()
                                WHERE CUSTOMER_LOCATION_ID = 16");

    $result = $query->result_array();
    if (empty($result)) {
        $data['utility_array'] = false;
    } else {
        $data['utility_array'] = $result;
    }

    $this->load->view('Customer',$data);   
}
```

**In View**

```
foreach ($utility_array as $value) {
    echo $value['ELECTRICITY_BILL_ID'];
    echo $value['TOTAL_AMOUNT'];
    echo "<br>";
}
```