# Convert inner join value to String - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am working in a school project using some CodeIgniter and I had a little problem while making a view.

Basically, I need to print a column value in the screen and, in order to get this value, I had to use an inner join.

```
form_label($this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT(MATERIA.NOME) FROM MATERIA INNER JOIN TURMA_has_MATERIA ON 
                            TURMA_has_MATERIA.MATERIA_idMATERIA = MATERIA.idMATERIA
                            WHERE MATERIA.idMATERIA = " . $thm->MATERIA_idMATERIA), "txt_1i")
```

The query works just fine when I use it in phpMyAdmin but it returns an array when used in a CodeIgniter view, resulting in an error. Is there any function that could help me to convert this value to something that could be printed? Thank you.

Comment: So loop through the array with `foreach( $result as $row ){ // ...`

Comment: [Here's an example of sending an array to a view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38730658/3585500).

Answer (score 1):

this is how I normally do joins and then print it in Codeigniter

[model]

```
function get_tutor_info($data) {
    $this->db->select('t1.id, t1.name, t2.nationality, t6.qualification');
    $this->db->from('user t1');
    $this->db->join('nationality t2', 't2.id = t1.nationality_id', 'inner');;
    $this->db->join('qualification t6', 't6.id = t4.qualification_id', 'inner');
    $this->db->where('t1.id', $data['tutor_id']);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result_array();
}
```

**[NOTE]** If you want to get an object instead of getting an array change the return at the top as such.

```
$query = $this->db->get();
$ret = $query->row();
return $ret->campaign_id;
```

[view]

```
<?php foreach($query as $row): ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row->id; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->nationality; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->qualification; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

If you want to know more about how to manipulate the results please refer to the [codeigniter documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html)

Hope this helped.

Comment: Also I would like to add that the Codeigniter documentation is one of the best ones I have ever seen. It covers almost everything you need to know in a very easy and readable fashion. Have a go at it once in a while if you are feeling stuck! :)